# Best way to configure timeouts on Apache HttpClient 5

Tags: java, spring, apache-httpcomponents, apache-httpclient-5.x

I'm trying to understand the difference between the various timeout configurations in HttpClient and the simplest way to configure it.

The various options are shown in this code:

```
RequestConfig requestConfig = RequestConfig.custom()
    .setConnectionRequestTimeout(connectionRequestTimeout, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
    .setResponseTimeout(responseTimeout, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
    .setConnectTimeout(connectTimeout, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS) // Deprecated - Use {@link ConnectionConfig.Builder#setConnectTimeout(Timeout)}.
    .build();
       
ConnectionConfig connectionConfig = ConnectionConfig.custom()
    .setConnectTimeout(connectTimeout, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
    .setSocketTimeout(socketTimeout, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
    .build();
       
SocketConfig socketConfig = SocketConfig.custom()
    .setSoTimeout(socketTimeout, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
    .build();
       
PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager poolingHttpClientConnectionManager = PoolingHttpClientConnectionManagerBuilder.create()
    .setDefaultConnectionConfig(connectionConfig)
    .setDefaultSocketConfig(socketConfig)
    .build();

HttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create()
    .setConnectionManager(poolingHttpClientConnectionManager)
    .setDefaultRequestConfig(requestConfig)
    .build();
```

My current understanding is this:

`ConnectionRequestTimeout` is the time taken to get a connection from the pool - relevant if under load.

`ConnectTimeout` is the time taken to establish the connection.

But what is the difference between:

```
RequestConfig.setResponseTimeout()
ConnectionConfig.setSocketTimeout()
SocketConfig.setSoTimeout()
```

they all seem to be read / response timeouts for a request. Do I only need to set one of these?
From some limited testing it seems `ResponseTimeout` overrides the others possibly implying thats all I need.

In this case it would be nice just to have to use `RequestConfig` to set all three but the `ConnectTimeout` has been deprecated there and moved to `ConnectionConfig` which also contains the `SocketTimeout`.

I'm using this with SpringBoot 3 / Spring 6 and the recent removal of the `readTimeout` configuration option on `HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory` seems to imply its best to set this up directly on the HttpClient.