Difference between different timeouts for apache http client 5.1
With Apache Http client 5.1.x, I want to set timeout on every HTTP request(Get, Post, ..), as I don't want to wait for more than certain period for obvious reasons. But I'm confused mostly between ConnectionRequestTimeout and ConnectTimeout. I've gone through some threads(eg.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78040298/best-way-to-configure-timeouts-on-apache-httpclient-5) but not able to understand the exact difference between them and which one to use for my use.
RequestConfig requestConfig =
          RequestConfig.custom()
              .setConnectionRequestTimeout(10)
              .setConnectTimeout(10)
              .setSocketTimeout(10)
              .setResponseTimeout(10)
              .build();


ConnectionRequestTimeout, ConnectTimeout, SocketTimeout, and ResponseTimeout
Each timeout (ConnectionRequestTimeout, ConnectTimeout, SocketTimeout, and ResponseTimeout) plays a critical role in ensuring that your HTTP requests are handled efficiently and do not lead to excessive wait times or timeouts. Understanding these timeouts allows you to configure HttpClient appropriately based on your application's needs and network environment.

ConnectionRequestTimeout: Set this to ensure you don't wait indefinitely for a connection from the connection manager.

ConnectTimeout: Set this to ensure you don't wait too long for establishing a connection to the remote server.

SocketTimeout: Set this to avoid waiting too long for data packets from the server.

ResponseTimeout: Set this to avoid waiting indefinitely for the complete response from the server.



Small correction. ResponseTimeout is the maximum period of inactivity until arrival of response head. It is presently is exactly the same as SocketTimeout for HTTP/1,1 and is not supported for H2 connections. This may change in the future versions of HttpClient.

GenAI content is not allowed on StackOverflow
